# How to add Days to a current Date in h2 database?

Tags: db2, h2

Query is executing in DB2 DB but its failing in H2 database:

```
SELECT P.CC_ID, MIN(P.CC_EXP_DT) CC_EXP_DT, MIN(P.PAYMT_TYP_CD) PAYMT_TYP_CD
    FROM Q.PAYMT P
    WHERE (P.PAYMT_BILLSTAT_CD = 'PD'
        OR (P.PAYMT_DUE_DT <= CURRENT DATE + CAST( 10 AS INT ) DAYS
        AND P.PAYMT_BILLSTAT_CD IN ('FB', 'RR', 'RP'))) AND (P.CC_ID IS NOT NULL)
        AND (P.INSTR_TYP_CD = 'EP') AND (P.PAYMT_TYP_CD IN ('VI', 'MC'))
    GROUP BY P.CC_ID
```

Error in H2 DB like :

> Error querying database.  Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax
>   error in SQL statement "SELECT P.CC_ID, MIN(P.CC_EXP_DT) CC_EXP_DT,
>   MIN(P.PAYMT_TYP_CD) PAYMT_TYP_CD FROM Q.PAYMT P WHERE
>   (P.PAYMT_BILLSTAT_CD = 'PD'  OR (P.PAYMT_DUE_DT <= CURRENT DATE +
>   CAST( 10 AS INT ) DAYS[*] AND P.PAYMT_BILLSTAT_CD IN ('FB', 'RR',
>   'RP'))) AND (P.CC_ID IS NOT NULL) AND (P.INSTR_TYP_CD = 'EP') AND
>   (P.PAYMT_TYP_CD IN ('VI', 'MC')) GROUP BY P.CC_ID"; expected "[, ::,
>   *, /, %, +, -, ||, ~, !~, NOT, LIKE, ILIKE, REGEXP, IS, IN, BETWEEN, AND, OR, ,, )"; SQL statement:

here DAYS[*] function in not available in H2 DB, please help me to execute above query

Comment: ...well, you could find [`DATEADD`](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#dateadd) in the h2 documentation, but that wouldn't help you much since the function doesn't exist on the DB2 side.  Date/time is one of those areas where every RDBMS does something slightly different.  You might have a better time extracting the date math out to your application layer and just providing it as a query parameter (this would make testing easier as well, since now system time is irrelevant)

Comment: thank you , but there no changes in query level

Comment: ...so what, exactly, is it you want to happen?  H2 doesn't have that syntax (it's not a function, which you could potentially write), so you can't execute that statement.  You'd have to change your query, but there isn't any common functionality you could use here (except extracting the date math to your application).  You could maybe fork H2, but that would be more effort than it was worth.